# Schengen business visa extension in Spain

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, visa-extensions

I'm travelling to Spain for business purpose and my visa is valid for just 14 days. Now I have another very urgent business to attend to in the Netherlands. Can I extend my stay for another 10 days to complete my business meeting in the Netherlands?

Can I get an extension in Spain, prior to entering the Netherlands? I haven't left for Spain yet and currently staying in my residence country (India).

Comment: The rules are the same than for other Schengen visas, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35710/extension-of-schengen-visa-within-90-days In a nutshell, it's generally not possible.

Comment: @Relaxed perhaps expand on that and put as an answer?

Comment: @Relaxed, just put the regulation in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [government of the Netherlands](http://www.government.nl/issues/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/question-and-answer/can-i-extend-a-schengen-visa-in-the-netherlands) provides a site that tells that you should be able to extend your visa:

> **Can I extend a Schengen visa in the Netherlands?**
>
> You can only extend a Schengen visa under special circumstances, for example if you are seriously ill. You will need to meet certain conditions. For example, your total stay must not exceed 90 days, and you will need to have enough money to support yourself.
>
> **Conditions for extending a Schengen visa**
>
> If you want to extend a Schengen visa, you must meet the following conditions:
>
> - Your stay must not exceed 90 days in total.
> - You must explain why you want to extend your stay and present documents on request showing that you cannot return to your country of origin before your visa period ends.
> - You must have enough money to support yourself as long as you remain in the Netherlands (at least €34 a day); or you must have someone in the Netherlands who can sponsor you.
> - You must remain covered by healthcare and/or travel insurance.
> - Your passport must be valid for at least a further six months and must not have been issued more than ten years ago.
> - There must be no indications that you have other reasons for extending your visa, such as the intention to settle illegally in the Netherlands.

So as long as you can prove to their satisfaction that you absolutely cannot leave the Schengen area until the meetings are completed you may be granted an extension.  Normally though it's reserved for the "Force Majeure" circumstances such as you're in a hospital.